# How to save a default printer in UserDefaults in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, printing, userdefaults

*This is the workflow of my app:*
User can select a default printer from app's settings page and will use this default printer to print every time directly **without any print preview dialogue**.

We can select a printer using `UIPrinterPickerController`:

```
let printerPicker = UIPrinterPickerController(initiallySelectedPrinter: nil)
printerPicker.present(from: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 500), in: self, animated: true) { (printerPicker, userDidSelect, error) in
    if userDidSelect {
        //Here get the selected UIPrinter
        let defaultPrinter = printerPicker.selectedPrinter
    }
}
```

After getting the `UIPrinter`, we can't directly save the `UIPrinter` object to UserDefaults, which is not a UserDefault support type.

Is there any other options to save `UIPrinter` to UserDefaults or any other way to save a default printer.

Comment: According to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprinter, you can save a printer's URL, and recreate the printer from that saved URL, but I never tried that myself.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/40610378 – That's Objective-C, but easily translated to Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store custom objects by `NSKeyedArchiver`. For that it to be encodable they must implement the NSCoding protocol.

But you can't store a `UIPrinter` instance in `NSUserDefaults`. After some research I have found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174540/saving-uiprinter-to-nsuserdefaults/37174962#37174802). Which says:

> You can't store a `UIPrinter` instance in `NSUserDefaults`. What you
>   can do is save the printer's URL and then when your app starts again
>   and you need the `UIPrinter`, read the URL from `NSUserDefaults` and
>   use `UIPrinter printerWithURL:`.

Comment: Wouldn't that require that UIPrinter conforms to NSCoding?